# Установить часовой пояс MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, linux, phpstorm

Всем привет.

Помогите разобраться. Каждый раз, когда я включаю компьютер у меня сбивается часовой пояс MySQL. Мне каждый раз приходится писать вот такую команду:

```
SET GLOBAL time_zone = '+2:00';
```

Может нужно будет - Linux/Ubuntu 18.04.

Я работаю в PhpStorm и мне нужно открыть бд в редакторе, а для того, чтобы она работала мне нужно зайти в терминал, зайти в mysql и установить часовой пояс той командой.

Можно ли как-то установить его и чтобы он не сбивался?

Comment: На самом сервере правильная таймзона? Думаю Мускул берет настройки ОС. Для дебиана и убунты (она на дебиане) можно сменить так: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Добавьте в файл `my.cnf` в секцию **[mysqld]** следующую строку:

```
default-time-zone='+02:00'
```

2. Перезапустите MySQL.

Значение часового пояса может быть задано в нескольких форматах:

- в качестве значения 'SYSTEM', означающее, что часовой пояс сервера совпадает с системным,
- смещение от UTC, например '-06:00', '+10:00',
- именованный часовой пояс, такой как 'Europe/Helsinki', 'US/Eastern'.

[Подробная информация в документации MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time-zone-support.html)

Comment: Где расположен этот файл в Linux ?

Comment: Посмотрите список возможных путей [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482234/how-do-i-find-the-mysql-my-cnf-location).